# Chi Square Test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, randomness

Would I use a chi square test to solve the following:

Use the attached data set for our company to address the following.

```
Rank        # of Persons    Sexual Orientation
Sr. Mgr.      1                M
Manager       9              4 M/ 5 F
Supervisor   20             12 M/ 8 F
Employee    100             51 M/49 F
```

Task assignments to employees are supposed to be done at random. On a certain day, all the best jobs, in order of desirability, were given to the men. Is there evidence of sex discrimination? Discuss this also in the context of a continuing, daily operation. What would happen if you tested the randomness hypothesis everyday?

Comment: 1. I would first consider the issues with (a) the apparent potential that the day was selected for testing *because* it looks unusual and the obvious problems that might present and (b) the issue with a process where you can observe it for long periods; certainly some days can look unusual. 2, The term "[sexual orientation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_orientation)" appears to be misused here, it seems like the intended  notion would be closer to *[gender identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gender_identity)* or *self-identified gender* though I'd expect some non-binary choices.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have two (homework?) problems. Both might be done
with chi-squared tests, as the title of your Question suggests.
I will show results from R, and let you verify chi-squared
statistics and decisions whether to accept the null hypothesis that type of job is independent of gender.

(a) Consider the $2\times 4$ table in which rows are for M/F and columns are for four job classes. In R:

```
m = c(1,4,12,51);  f = c(0,5,8,49)
TBL = rbind(m, f);  TBL

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
m    1    4   12   51
f    0    5    8   49
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 1.6778, df = 3, p-value = 0.6419

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

The chi-squared test compares observed counts in `TAB` with
expected counts found from marginal totals, assuming the
null hypothesis is true. The warning message is shown
because sone of the expected counts are smaller than $5.$
In that case the chi-squared statistic (`X-squared` in output)
may not have the distribution $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 3).$

The expected counts (unrounded, as appropriate) can be
displayed as shown below. [You should try to verify a few
of them by hand computation.]

```
chisq.test(TBL)$exp

       [,1]     [,2]      [,3]     [,4]
m 0.5230769 4.707692 10.461538 52.30769
f 0.4769231 4.292308  9.538462 47.69231
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Notice that the first two columns have small expected counts.
A traditional method would be to combine the first two (managerial) categories into one, giving a $2\times 4$ table.
I will let you try that on your own.

An alternative method, available in R, is to simulate a
more realistic P-value. For your data there is not
enough data to reject $H_0$ at the 5% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL, sim=T)$p.val
[1] 0.7671164
```

If you wanted to test whether the percentage of women among
managers/supervisors and employees, then you could do a
chi-squared test on a $2\times 2$ table or use `prop.test`,
which uses a slightly different method of data input.
The mgmt/sup class has  about 57% men and the emp class has
51% men. While these two proportions are different, the difference is not large enough to be called 'statistically
significant' at the 5% level because the P-value $0.74 > 0.05 = 5\%.$ [Because counts are mainly below 100, I have kept
the default 'continuity correction'.] Results form
a chi-squared test on the appropriate $2 \times 2$ table.

```
M = c(25, 0);  W = c(0, 35)
TAB = rbind(M, W);  TAB
  [,1] [,2]
M   25    0
W    0   35

prop.test(c(17, 51), c(30, 100))

    2-sample test for equality of proportions 
    with continuity correction

data:  c(17, 51) out of c(30, 100)
X-squared = 0.11332, df = 1, p-value = 0.7364
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.1675904  0.2809237
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.5666667 0.5100000
```

(b)  One numerical interpretation: Suppose there were 60 jobs altogether (25 of them 'best')
all assigned to men, with the other 35 jobs all assigned
to women. Then a $2 \times 2$ table with rows for Men and
Women and columns for Best and Worst would be as shown below.

```
M = c(25, 0);  W = c(0, 35)
TAB = rbind(M, W);  TAB
  [,1] [,2]
M   25    0
W    0   35

chisq.test(TAB)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test 
    with Yates' continuity correction

data:  TAB
X-squared = 55.956, df = 1, p-value = 7.41e-14

prop.test(c(25,0), c(25, 35))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(25, 0) out of c(25, 35)
X-squared = 55.956, df = 1, p-value = 7.41e-14
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.9657143 1.0000000
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 
     1      0
```

Both `chisq.test` and `prop.test` give P-values very near $0.$
indicating strong gender preference in the assignment of
job types, rather than random assignment.

In a prior era, this might have been "explained" by saying
that all managers and supervisors and a few "outstanding"
employees (mostly men) were given primary consideration for the Best jobs, and that all of those chosen just "happened to be men."

Nowadays, in the US,
I suppose that some lawsuits claiming "blatant gender discrimination" might test this explanation.
At the very least, it seems that employers are not doing much to foster the careers of their female employees.